# Error with APAddressBOOK: "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Tags: arrays, swift, addressbook

I am receiving this strange error every time I process an address book ( using APAddressBOOK via cocapods) in Swift and after some debugging I found out that and empty object *(record with no phone number*) within the array causes this issue but am not sure how to get rid of it.

Here is my code:

```
func getPersonsNo(contactno: AnyObject) -> String {
    println(contactno) // **when the object is empty I get this "[]"**
            if let numberRaw = contactno.phones?[0] as? String { // at this statement the program crashes with a fatal error 
        println(numberRaw)
        return numberRaw)
    }

    return " "
}
```

Any clues what is happening here?

Comment: The subscript of an array doesn't return an optional if it's out of range of the array. Therefore, when `contactno` is empty your program will crash because there's no element at index 0 of the array.

Comment: Any suggestions how do I avoid this situation. I have replaced the optional with "!" but am still running into the fatal crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscript of an `Array` doesn't return an optional to indicate if an index is out of range of the array; instead your program will crash with the message “fatal error: Array index out of range”. Applying this your code: when `contactno` is empty your program will crash because there's no element at index 0 of the array.

To easiest way to solve your problem is probably to use the `first` property on `Array`. `first` will return the first element in the array, or `nil` if the array is empty. Taking a look at how `first` is declared:

```
extension Array {
    var first: T? { get }
}
```

As of Swift 2, `first` has been made an extension of the `CollectionType` protocol:

```
extension CollectionType {
    var first: Self.Generator.Element? { get }
}
```

You'd use this like so:

```
if let numberRaw = contactno.phones?.first as? String { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks  ABakerSmith I wish I had the advance knowledge of using extension in Swift but I am just beginning to learn my way through. I will need some hand holding here.  I have added the extension before the beginning of the class and the compiler is throwing error   import Foundation

extension Array {
    /// Returns the first element of `self`, or `nil` if `self` is empty.
    var first: T? { get }
}
error: " expected "{" to start getter definition"

Comment: You don't need to add any extensions, that was just there to show you how `first` was declared. You can use `first` just like the example I gave at the end of my answer :) `first` just returns the first element in a collection (an array in your case); it's an easier and safer alternative to `phones[0]`.

Comment: Oh boy that is embarrassing!!   back to the tutorials. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that's all working for you :) Good luck with your project!